# Memberships - Receipt (on-line) template: how to check if it is a subscription or a renew

Tags: civimember, tokens, renewals

I would customize the template *Memberships - Receipt (on-line)* in order to give a different message if it is a signup or a renewal.
I try a lot of tokens, but no ones works:
$receiptType
$membership_status
$membership_source
$source
$status
$membershipStatus
$form.receipt_text
$formValues.receipt_text_signup
$formValues.receipt_text_renewal
$formValues.receipt_text
$formValues.receipt_text.label
$receipt_text
$receipt_text.label

In the offline template I use $receiptType EQ 'membership signup'.

Have you any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution, not perfect, but it works for me: I use the $mem_status token and check if it is New. In this case I assume that it is a signup else it is a renew